# Step assertion based on different step result - soapUI (run test case and test step from script assertion)

Tags: groovy, soapui

In a Soapui test case I've an "update" soap test step. Right after this I've a groovy script step in which I am verifying this "update" by running a different test step,say "search" (located in a different test case),  programmatically from withing this script. Now, I would like to mark "update" step as pass or fail from script assertion (so i can get that green/red thing), based on the result of "search".

As `testRunner` is not available in script assertion (as per my knowledge) , how do I assert on "update" based on "search". Because "search" has to run between the run of "update" and the run of assertion script of "update". I've tried using `context` object as described [here](http://www.doan.me/script-library-in-soapui-free.aspx), but failing  script assertion doest not show access to properties that are set in this `context` object in a groovy script step.

Has anyone faced such issue? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your test structure is confusing; maybe you should rethink that. How about showing some code: what's working, what not?

Comment: @SiKing May be I explained in a confusing way or gave too much infor but in short , I would like to run a test step located in a different test case from script assertion of a step and assert based on the results recieved. So i was looking for a "handle" in script assertion, to run the test step in a different TC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by running testcase from assertion script like this.

```
messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("Test Case Name").run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false)
```

Also, a test step can be run from assert script like this.

```
messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getTestStepByName("Test step Name").run(context.getTestRunner(),context)
```

Comment: `context.getTestRunner()` returns `null` for me when I use it in an assertion